# Simutaneously evaluate two expression in the same notebook

Tags: parallelization, kernel

Suppose I have two expressions in the same note book but in different cells, both of them take much time to evaluate. In general, mathematica waits until the first expression is done, then evaluate the second one.

How can I evaluate the second simultaneously? Suppose I have two cores on my computer.

Comment: Have you looked into the `Parallel*` functionalities?